# Get current datetime in QDateTimeEdit

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

This is my first time using Qt Designer, I create function to get datetime data and then store as string in textedit

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5 import uic

Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType("datetime2.ui")


class MyApp(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyApp,self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.GetDatetime)

    def GetDatetime(self):
        dt = self.ui.dateTimeEdit.dateTime()
        dt_string = dt.toString(self.ui.dateTimeEdit.displayFormat())
        self.ui.textEdit.setText(dt_string)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if not QApplication.instance():
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    else:
        app = QApplication.instance() 
    window = MyApp()
    window.show()
    app.exec()
```

Here the output

[image: image 1]

When I change dateTimeEdit column and press button the button, the value in edit text also change.

My question is, how to set datetime with local time every open the program ? 
And my second question how to show the second's time, because when I ran the program, can't shown second's value ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to have the current time using [`QDateTime.currentDateTime()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html#currentDateTime) and set it in the [`QDateTimeEdit`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetimeedit.html) using the [`setDateTime()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetimeedit.html#dateTime-prop) method.

To show the seconds you must set a [`displayFormat`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetimeedit.html#displayFormat-prop) that shows the seconds, for example: `dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss`.

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, uic

Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType("datetime2.ui")


class MyApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyApp, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.GetDatetime)
        self.ui.dateTimeEdit.setDateTime(QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime())
        self.ui.dateTimeEdit.setDisplayFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss")

    def GetDatetime(self):
        dt = self.ui.dateTimeEdit.dateTime()
        dt_string = dt.toString(self.ui.dateTimeEdit.displayFormat())
        self.ui.textEdit.setText(dt_string)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()
    if app is None:
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Thanks, it works like a charm ! Anyway how get output become "2019-07-22T11:08:52+07:00" in textEdit column ?

Comment: @ilhamramadhan what is `07:00`?

Comment: it's my timezone, anyway I found the solutions. `self.ui.dateTimeEdit.setDisplayFormat("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss+07:00")`

Comment: @ilhamramadhan that's not really your display format is it?  That's not good.
Perhaps try using like setDisplayFormat(Qt::ISODate), or something else involving the 'Zulu' specifiers, like... "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss[Z|[+|-]HH:mm]"